# Explorer tooltips inside buttons

Tags: html, css

Tooltip css:

```
.mainButtonContainer button:hover:after
{

    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-color: #093466;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 2px 2px;
    bottom: -5px;
    color: #093466;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 113px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

html:

```
<button  id=mgf_main1 type="button" onclick="loadData(1)">
    <img src="Images/Magof-Icon.png" width="68" height="68"/>
</button>
```

The tooltip looks fine int Firefox, Chrome ect.

[image: Firefox]

But the problem is in IE (10)

[image: Explorer]

The tooltip is contained to the size of button, how can I fix this?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle......

Comment: This demo http://jsfiddle.net/rdRhS/ seems to work in ie10 - maybe post your full code? ..

Comment: Also, in the code you posted - there's no content: '' rule which is obviously necessary for the after pseudo element

Comment: Yes, that`s it! Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.mainButtonContainer button { overflow: visible } – DJDavid98